# Сопоставление двух списков Python

Tags: python, list

К примеру есть следующие списки:

```
l1 = ["abc3", "abc3", "abc3"]
l2 = ["word1", "abc3", "list"]
```

Результат сравнения двух списков(l1, l2) должен вернуть False, поскольку элементы списка l2 повторяются в списке l1 один раз

```
l3 = ["abc3", "word1", "zzzzzz"]
l4 = ["word1", "abc3", "list"]
```

Результат сравнения двух списков(l3, l4) должен вернуть True, поскольку элементы списка l4 повторяются в списке l3 два раза.

```
l5 = ["word1", "zzzz", "z"]
l6 = ["word1", "abc3", "list"]
```

Результат сравнения двух списков(l5, l6) должен вернуть False, поскольку элементы списка l6 повторяются в списке l5 один раз.

```
l6 = ['1', '2', '1']
l7 = ['2', '2', '2']
```

Результат сравнения двух списков(l6, l7) должен вернуть False, поскольку элементы списка l7 повторяются в списке l6 три раза.

Другими словами, то в сравнении двух списков должно быть не более чем одно не совпадение.

Если списки одинаковые, то результат будет True, так как списки совпадают.

```
l7 = ["1", "word"]
l8 = ["word", "1"]
```

Comment: l2 - двенадцать

Answer (score 2):

Создаём из первого списка множество. Элементы второго списка проверяем на вхождение в это множество:

```
def check(list1, list2):
    s = set(list1)
    c = sum(1 for v in list2 if v in s)
    return c >= len(list2) - 1

print(check(
    ["abc3", "abc3", "abc3"],
    ["word1", "abc3", "list"]
))

print(check(
    ["abc3", "word1", "zzzzzz"],
    ["word1", "abc3", "list"]
))

print(check(
    ["word1", "zzzz", "z"],
    ["word1", "abc3", "list"]
))

print(check(
    ['1', '2', '1'],
    ['2', '2', '2']
))
```

> ```
> $ python check.py
> False
> True
> False
> False
> ```

Comment: А как быть, если есть списки с одинаковыми элементами ["1", "word"], ["1", "word"] или  ["1", "word"], ["word", "1"] ? По условию задачи должен быть True, поскольку расхождений нету.

Comment: Поправил код...

Answer (score 0):

Всё-равно до конца не совсем понятно, что делать, например, если размер списков разный и точно ли мы первый список берём за основу. Но в общем например так:

```
def comp_list(l1, l2):
    return len(set(l2) - set(l1)) <= 1

print(comp_list(l1, l2)) # False
print(comp_list(l3, l4)) # True
print(comp_list(l5, l6)) # False
```

Comment: там по условию задачи если разной длины, то проверку и не стоит проводить. Ваш ответ  работает, спасибо.

Comment: l6 = ['1', '2', '1'] ; l7 = ['2', '2', '2']  столкнулся с такими списками по задаче, должно вернуть False, а по Вашему решению возвращает True

Comment: Ага, ну то есть нужно считать одинаковые элементы. Тогда надо подумать.

Answer (score 0):

вот, ради эксперимента:

```
import pandas as pd

l1 = ["abc3", "abc3", "abc3"]
l2 = ["word1", "abc3", "list"]
l3 = ["abc3", "word1", "zzzzzz"]
l4 = ["word1", "abc3", "list"]
l5 = ["word1", "zzzz", "z"]
l6 = ["word1", "abc3", "list"]
l7 = ['1', '2', '1']
l8 = ['2', '2', '2']

def cmp_lst(lst1: list, lst2: list) -> bool:
    return True if len(pd.DataFrame(index = lst1).
                       join(pd.DataFrame(index = lst2), how="inner")) == 2 else False

print(cmp_lst(l1, l2))
print(cmp_lst(l3, l4))
print(cmp_lst(l5, l6))
print(cmp_lst(l7, l8))
```

```
False
True
False
False
```

Comment: `True if <condition> else False` -> `<condition>`.

Answer (score 0):

return sorted(l1) == sorted(l2)

Если в списках равные значения, вернется True, Если хоть 1 значение отличается, вернется False